# Counting vowels in a text file with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to count the vowels in a lengthy text, provided by a .txt file. I can successfully open the file and echo it out into the browser. What I can't seem to do is get my script to do the actual vowel counting and I'm not entirely sure why. I'm supposed to output the vowel count to a file that doesn't previously exist, but is referred to as "file_output1.txt". I'm not sure if this is what is causing the issue, or if I'm not properly accessing the text file (Assignment Input) to enable the count to occur, or if I made a syntax error my eyes just can't seem to catch right now.

This is what I've done so far, but I'm not getting the count to fill. There are hundreds of vowels in the text file and it keeps spitting out: "There are (0) vowels". I have counted letters in a string before, but I am having trouble doing it with the file. Any advice?

```
<?php
#openfile
$file = "Assignment2inputfile.txt" ;
$document = fopen($file,r);
echo fread($document,filesize("Assignment2inputfile.txt"));
?>
<html>
<br><br>
</html>
<?php
#vowelcount
$vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"); 
$length = strlen($_POST["file_output1.txt"]);
$count = 0; 
for ($i =0; $i = $length; $i++)
{
    if (array_search($_POST["file_output1.txt"][$i], $vowels))
    {
        $count++; 
    }
}
echo 'There are (' . $count . ') vowels ' . $_POST["file_output1.txt"] .'.';  
fclose($document);  
?>
```

I have counted letters before, but this time it is not a short string input. How can I do this for vowels, but with a FILE instead of a string?

Comment: Well if you done this for a string before, then now all you would have to do, is read the file contents into a string - and then proceed from there, same as you did before - no …?

Comment: `for ($i =0; $i <= $length; $i++)` You overwrite $i with length.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `regex` to do this quite simply

```
    $text='The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog';
    $pttn='@[aeiouAEIOU]@';
    preg_match_all( $pttn, $text, $matches );


    printf( '<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $matches, true ) );
    printf('There are %d vowels',count($matches[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `array_search` is meant for finding a key of a value inside an array.  But, you want to count the number of vowels in a string.

Since you have already read the entire file into memory, one simple approach here would be to just strip all vowels, and then compare the length of the resulting string against the original length:

```
$text = $_POST["file_output1.txt"];
$length = strlen($text);
$new_text = preg_replace("/[aeiou]/i", "", $text);

echo "Number of vowels: " . ($length - strlen($new_text));
```

Here is a brief demo showing that the above logic is working:

### Demo

Comment: this is a really smart solution! chapeaux! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have updated code.

```
<?php
    $file     = "Assignment2inputfile.txt";
    $document = fopen($file, 'r');
    $output   = fread($document, filesize("Assignment2inputfile.txt"));
    $vowels = array(
        "a",
        "e",
        "i",
        "o",
        "u"
    );
    $length = strlen($output);
    $count  = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        if (array_search($output[$i], $vowels)) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    echo 'There are (' . $count . ') vowels ' . $count . '.';
    fclose($document);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand, are you trying to echo the file then read it via $_POST ???. That wouldn't work. If you're using a single php file then try

```
$file = "Assignment2inputfile.txt" ;
$document = fopen($file,r);
$str = fread($document,filesize("Assignment2inputfile.txt"));
```

Now you can use $str as

```
$vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"); 
$length = strlen($str);
$count = 0; 
for ($i =0; $i = $length; $i++)
{
    if (array_search($str[$i], $vowels))
    {
        $count++; 
    }
}
```

finally write it to required file.
P.S I haven't completely understood your question but this should help if you're trying a normal read from a local file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this:

> I'm trying to count the vowels in a lengthy text, provided by a .txt
>   file[...] I have counted letters in a string before, but I am having
>   trouble doing it with the file. Any advice?

You can use the following line of code to count only vowels in a file

```
str_ireplace(['a','e','u','i','o'],' ',file_get_contents('Assignment2inputfile.txt'),$count);
```

We basically simulate an insensitive case replacement while keeping track of the number of replacements which give exactly what you need the number of vowels

Then based on this:

> I'm supposed to output the vowel count to a file that doesn't
>   previously exist, but is referred to as "file_output1.txt".

```
file_put_contents("file_output1.txt",sprintf('There are %d vowels ',$count));
```

we use this line of code to create a new file if not exists and put a formatted string with the number of vowels as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**First possibility** that you are sending `$_POST['file_output1.txt']` from another file to here displayed file.

if you are not getting any POST data or All you have is here displayed sample file, then my friend you are wrong, you have to take form and form fields like text-field, textarea etc,

and you have to submit it at here displayed file with post request so you can take `$_POST` variable, i am assuming that you are doing right then your code is fine except it has 2 errors like below:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant r - assumed 'r' in C:\xampp\htdocs\stackplay\count_vowels.php on line 4
```

1. You have used (file operation mode) **`r` in `fopen($file,'r')` function without quote , it should be in single or double quote** 
   see the syntax here [fopen (string $filename , string $mode)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)
2. second error is **logical error in `for loop`** You have written `for ($i =0; $i = $length; $i++)` so it will assign `length` of file content to `$i` in first iteration and loop runs infinitely still occur execution time out or allocated memory exhausts, so to solve it **replace it with `for ($i =0; $i < $length; $i++)`**

**Second Possibility** that you are not getting any POST data or All you have is file displayed in sample code in question, then i am giving you solution as below:

**Assignment2inputfile.txt** File:

`The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog`

**count_vowels.php** File:

```
<?php
#openfile
$file = "Assignment2inputfile.txt" ;
$document = fopen($file,'r');

$text =  fread($document,filesize("Assignment2inputfile.txt"));
fclose($document);  
?>
<html>
<br><br>
</html>
<?php
#vowelcount
$vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"); 

$length = strlen($text);
$count = 0; 
for ($i =0; $i < $length; $i++)
{
  if (array_search($text[$i], $vowels))
  {
    $count++; 
  }
}
echo 'There are (' . $count . ') vowels in : ' . $text .'.';   
?>



//Output:
//There are (11) vowels in : The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```

There can be lots of solution to count vowels from text file but i am only showing how to do it rightly, please comment if anywhere i am wrong, thanks.